# Php compare external value to array value if matched

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

I have this Array (`$item`):

```
Array
        (

            [categoria] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [tid] => 6737
                            [name] => Sala VIP
                            [endereco] => 
                            [logo] => 
                            [image] => 
                            [link] => /taxonomy/term/6737
                            [site] => 
                            [color] => 
                            [peso] => 0
                            [icone] => 1
                            [url_emissores] => 
                        )

                )

            [destaque] => 1
        )
```

And i want to compare if `$something` is equal to `[name] => Sala VIP`. How can i do this? Im trying:

```
if($something == $item[categoria][0].name) {
   #code
}
```

Comment: `$item['categoria'][0]['name']`

Comment: @Jonnix Thanks man <3 You're awesome

Comment: @Jonnix is it really necessary to use '         '  between words? cant it be just $item[categoria][0][name] ?

Comment: @VitorMascia It _can_ work, but I wouldn't recommend it. Without quotes it will try and use constants with those names first, rather than treating them as strings. For the sake of 2 `'`, just use an explicit string.

Comment: @VitorMascia - you can use it but you will get a warning.  `Use of undefined constant foo assuming 'foo'`  or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned above, you can access an index of an array like `['someIndex']`. But if this array is not a constant, you should ensure that that field is actually set or you will get an undefined index error.

Adding an [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) before comparing will prevent such errors:

```
if(isset($item['categoria'][0]['name']) && $item['categoria'][0]['name'] === $something) {
   #code
}
```

Hope this helps,